# Prevent wrapping inline code

Tags: support, code-formatting

I've just made an edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/667754/revisions), but the way the inline code wraps is not sensible.

---

[image: Bad wrap]

---

Is there a way to indicate that `" ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv))` should not be broken over lines?

I don't want to actually change the code by, e.g., putting in a non-breaking space character or some other Unicode trick, because it would alter the meaning of the code when copied and pasted. And I don't want to reword the prose just to workaround this. It should remain working even when other people make future edits.

Comment: My preference here would probably just be... Use a one line code block rather than inline code.

Comment: That's probably what I'd do if it was my own answer, too. But I'm still interested to know a technique for no-wrap on inline code, if any such technique exists.

Comment: I guess `<code>"&nbsp;".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv))</code>` would work, at least for now.

Comment: @Kaiido That might cause problems if people copy it and expect it to be a normal space.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I must admit I didn't try with the server-side renderer but from the front-end one (using below answer box) it seems that copying this character would copy a normal space (at least on my macOS Firefox, it may be system dependent).

Comment: @Kaiido Seems to copy a normal space (on Chrome/Windows). See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380178/348196

Comment: It seems to me like the natural fix for this is for the site to just never wrap inline code; I don't think it ever improves clarity (if the length of the inline code causes layout problems, that's a warning flag for the person writing it instead).

Answer (score 3):

There will always be some ambiguities when determining where to insert line breaks in code. Short of inserting a character that instructs the browser to not break the word here, I have no idea how you would programmatically go about this. I have run into this before. It's a little frustrating that `a quick line of code` mid-sentence wraps in a strange way, but remember this site is displayed on a number of different form factors. It might look funny on a nice, wide desktop monitor, but look just fine on a tablet or mobile phone. You could even fiddle with the wording of your answer so it shows up fine when composing the answer only to find out it looks funny on a mobile phone.

Instead (and I know this isn't news to you), I just put the code in code fences:

> ... You could get something equivalent using:
>
> ```
> " ".join(map(shlex.quote, sys.argv))
> ```
>
> though you shouldn't need to...

It might not be as nice as reading it inline, but at least it isn't wrapped funny.

---

And just to illustrate this problem a little more, my answer even includes such an awkward break:

[image: Screenshot of this answer with an awkward wrapping of inline code]

Comment: Illustrating the problem *even further*, your answer [doesn't have an awkward break](https://i.imgur.com/A1hZcxA.png) for me.